# Bounding a bilinear map

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $B$ be a bilinear map from $R^p \times R^q$  to $R^N$. Prove that there exists a $C>0$ s.t. $\left\lvert\lvert B(u,v)\right\rvert\rvert \le \lvert\lvert u\rvert\rvert \cdot\lvert\lvert v\rvert\rvert\cdot C$.
I am having trouble proving this. I know that $B(u,\cdot): R^q\to R^N$ is linear and linear maps are bounded. But I don't know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $B$ as a linear map $u \in \mathbb R^p \mapsto B(u,-) \in \hom(\mathbb R^q,\mathbb R^N)$. Then there exists $C > 0$ such that

$$
\|B(u,-)\| \leq C\|u\|
$$

for all $u$, because as you say linear maps are bounded. Now, we have:

$$
\|B(u,v)\| = \|B(u,-)(v)\| \leq \|B(u,-)\|\|v\| \leq C\|u\|\|v\|.
$$

Comment: Thank u! I was not sure if B(u,v) = B(u,-)(v), but it all makes sense now!